# MIPS: Branch using indirect jump?

Tags: code-generation, mips, addressing

Suppose a label called L1. On MIPS, one can easily do:

```
beq $t1, $t2, L1
```

But is there a way to do the same using **indirect addressing**? By that, I mean using a register that holds the address where `L1` is found. I know of the `jr` command, but I don't see how it could be used for this purpose.

Comment: There's no MIPS tag here because this is a computer science site, not a programming site. Migrating…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beq` requires an immediate value in its 3rd argument, never a register or memory address.

According to page 55 of [this manual](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/MIPS_Vol2.pdf) (page 63 in the PDF), the range of `beq` is -128 KB to +128KB, which is exactly 4 times as much as a signed 16-bit integer can represent: -32 KB to +32 KB (since instructions are 4 bytes long, a multiplier of 4 is automatically applied).

I think `jr` should be able to accomplish what you want. Instead of using a register to point to memory address XX, just load the value of address XX into a register and use that to jump.

```
lw $t0, XX
jr $t0
```